# Mail Server user management issue using Postfix+Dovecot+RainLoop

Tags: centos, email, password, postfix, dovecot

I'm using mail server using postfix+dovecot (over TLS/SSL), RainLoop as my WebClient, and using `auth-system.conf.ext` so user's password will be read by/from pam.

Consider at least 10 users using this mail-server everyday, so it's not a good idea to give them shell access, so I changed their shell to `/sbin/nologin`.

Everything is working great, but users cannot change their password.  At the current state, RainLoop, OutLook, ThunderBird and etc. are not able to let the user change his/her password. There is something in RainLoop, called `poppassd`, I'm not sure if this can help me or not. I'm open to any solution, I just need to know what I should do to let them change their password, and I have no idea myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Email users should be in MySQL, not in PAM, and certainly not as system users.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Can they easily change their password with no extra means in that case?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm not an expert in using MySQL, I'll be highly thankful if you can help me a bit by explaining a bit more details.

Comment: If you give them webmail access they can change their own passwords. In my case, users are synchronised with our AD. Beware `poppassd` changes the system passwords, is a concept from the 90s when Eudora was king and dinosaurs roamed the earth, and is a security risk.

Comment: Setting up a postfix server properly configured is not an easy task https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Great, thanks. I set up a new mail server using MySQL as you said, and it's working. But there are two problems I'm facing with at the moment. Shall I ask you to read my newly asked question [HERE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313965/mail-server-send-receive-issues) and help me if you can? Thanks.

Comment: This script was made to setup Postfix and Dovecot to use with Rainloop:  https://github.com/hardware/mailserver-autoinstall Hope it help others.